# Unable to replace React env.js variables using Replace Tokens or BashScript in Azure DevOps Release pipeline

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops, environment-variables, cicd, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working on updating the environment variables in my React application using the Azure DevOps Release pipeline. While I've successfully replaced them in the CI build pipeline, I now need to extend this to support multiple environments in the Release pipeline.

Initially, I tried using .env files for variable management, but the Release pipeline didn't replace them from the build artifact. As a workaround, I created an env.js file to store the variables and attempted to replace them in the bundle.js file. However, I'm still struggling to replace the production variables with the values from the variable group in the Release pipeline.

[image]

[image]

As this didn't work, I tried using Bash script with sed commands.

[image]

I'm still getting this error. Could someone please help.
[image]

[image]
[image]

CI pipeline images below:
[image]

Location of env.js in the code strucutre
[image]

The kind of artifact, release pipeline is consuming
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Based on the further discussions, to configure the `ReplaceToken` task to replace the variables' names in the `env.js` file with their respective values, we need to **either** define the variable value directly in the release pipeline **or** link a variable group where the variables are restored.

[image]

At the same time, we need to make sure the target `env.js` file is downloaded as an artifact, so that the `ReplaceToken` task is able to find and process it.

In your screenshot, the `env.js` file should be downloaded in the folder or the sub folder of `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Trusana-UI-POC/drop/patient/` for the `ReplaceToken` task to search for. For this, I used the commands below in a `Bash` task running on the `ubuntu-latest` agent to confirm if the target file was downloaded under path `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Trusana-UI-POC/drop/patient/` and check the file contents after value replacement.

```
tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Trusana-UI-POC/drop/patient/

cat $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Trusana-UI-POC/drop/patient/env.js
```

[image]

---

From the screenshots that you shared, it seemed that you would replace the variables' names in the `env.js` file with their values; however, in the release pipeline, you were targeting another file `bundles.js`.

Please modify your pipeline to target the correct file where the pipeline variables were included.

**env.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "REACT_APP_ApiBaseUrl" : "#{apiBaseUrl}#"
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried changing it to env.js, still it gives the same logs. 'replaced 0 tokens out of 0 in 0 file(s) in 0.016 seconds'
Could you confirm if you got env.js in the artifact drop? I don't have it generated. I'll paste the changed Pipeline task screenshot above.- Alvin Zhao

Comment: Do I need to specifically mention the variable group in the Release pipeline tasks?

Comment: Hi @Fayazshaik, Thanks for the update. I have shared some more details to help understand how to use the `ReplaceToken` task and check if the target file is downloaded in the expected path. If you are using a Linux agent, you may test to use `tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` command in `Bash` to list all the files in the working directory of the release pipeline and configure the `ReplaceToken` task to find the target file `env.js`. For a Windows agent, you can use `tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) /F /A` in a `PowerShell` task.

Comment: I followed your steps mentioned above, and as I suspected, env.js file isn't coming up in the build artifact.
cat: /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_Trusana-UI-POC/drop/patient/env.js: No such file or directory. How do I make sure env.js file turns up in my artifact build drop?

Comment: Not sure why you created `env.js` file and then would expect to modify another file. If you would use `ReplaceToken`  task to modify certain parts/contents in the `bundles.js` file, the target file should be `bundles.js`. The `ReplaceToken` task won't read variable value from `env.js` file but from the **pipeline variables** section.  You may directly use the same pattern `#{VariableName}#` in `bundles.js` file, as you used in the `env.js` file -> Link the variable group where the variables are stored -> Configure `ReplaceToken` task find `bundles.js` in its correct download location.

Comment: @Fayazshaik, Have you tested to `tree $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` to list all files? Is `env.js` file under any other subfolder in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`? If it is not downloaded togher with other artifact files, you may first need to check whether you have published this file as a build pipline or not in your **CI** pipeline.

Comment: yes I tried it. There is no env.js in the entire tree generated in the logs. pls suggest what can I try next?

Comment: I pasted my CI build pipeline screenshot above and also have located the env.js in the code structure. could you please take a look and suggest?

Comment: Can you please share what type of aritifact your release pipeline consumed, Repo or Artifacts built by a CI pipeline? Assuming the `env.js` file is generated in your `Azure Repo`, Is your release pipeline directly downloading files from your repo or downloading the artifacts published during your build pipeline run? I lack the information and cannot provide a tailored sample for your reference. I would like to suggest further with more information.

Comment: I will generate a build pipeline based on your description and come back to you shortly.

Comment: I have added a last screenshot, could you please confirm if the information is sufficient?

Comment: Hi @Fayazshaik, I don't think `env.js` was published as one of the build artifact files duriing your CI pipeline run. From your code structure, `env.js` was under the path of `$(Build.SourceDirectory)/apps/patient`; however you published the files copied from `$(Build.SourceDirectory)/apps/patient/build` as the build artifacts; `env.js` files was not located there and the published artifacts didn't include `env.js`. This was why the release pipeline couldn't find the `env.js` file. Please check if you have published all the required files for your app deloyment.

Comment: thank you so much for your response, I got feedback not to use env.js and instead fix the issue with .env file. I've posted a new question here, could you please take a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78148910/unable-to-read-dynamic-env-variables-post-the-replace-tokens-in-the-azure-dev