# Unable to read dynamic '.env' variables post the Replace tokens in the Azure DevOps Release pipeline

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, .env

I need to replace .env variables in the Azure DevOps release pipeline. I have used 'Replace tokens' task for the same. I have verified that the task is able to replace my variables from the variable group, but still, the application is not able to read the deployed variables.
Adding screenshots below for more understanding.

Here is my CI build pipeline

[image]

.env file from the code

[image]

I use replace tokens to replace the env variables from the artifact drop

[image]

Task to show content post the replacement of variables

[image]

Logs confirming tokens replaced in the task

[image]

show content logs confirming the replaced variables

[image]

But, when I run the application for making an api call, I still see Not replaced token variable in the console.log.
I'm reading the variables in the code using process.env.{VariableName}

[image]

I think the variables are getting replaced in the .env file but as the .env file is not a part of the build folder which gets deployed, the changes are not reflecting in the target environment. Could someone help here?

Comment: It looks like the log confirming the replaced variables has a later timestamp than the 'variable not found'. My guess would be a multithreading issue of some type.

Comment: No no, my target 4 variables got replaced. The issue is that the deployed application is unable to read it. I use process.env to read the variables in the code. but in the last screenshot , as you can see the variable didn't get replaced. check console.log

Comment: Hi @Fayazshaik, Good day to you. May I know if it is required to define all the **8** variables with their value in the release pipeline? Since you have 4 variables' names replaced with their values during the release, I suspect you miss nomination of the other 4 variables. Please check the variables tab of the release pipeline and **don't** disclose any sensitive information in the publicly visible community. Thx.

Comment: In addition, if the `.env` file got processed by the `ReplaceToken` task and deployed correctly to the expected app service, the file with the **updated** contents should be deployed. How did the `cat` command print the `.env` contents? The task name in your screenshot was `show the contents of bundle.js`. Could there be any chance that your patient app was deployed to another app or staging slot?

Comment: Hi @AlvinZhao, I'm replacing the variables within the drop itself before it gets deployed. Also, the task to show contents is for .env itself post replacement and not bundle.js. please verify in the screenshots above, and I'm deploying the app to the right slot itself.

Comment: Please take a look at your second to last screenshot. The last line says `2024-03-12T06:42:03.5010657Z ##[section]Finishing: Show contents in bundles.js` rather than `Finishing: Show contents post token replacement`. please verify in the screenshots above and check if you uploaded a wrong screenshot.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But still, every target is an expected one here. I just think that, variable replacement is happening in .env but the .env is not a part of the build folder. Hence, it is not reflecting in the deployment. Any idea how to include the .env inside build folder?

Comment: I am a little confused here. Based on your description, you would like the `token replacement` is happening in `.env` file, which is located in the path of release pipeline `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Trusana-UI-POC/drop/patient`, right? But what do you mean by `the .env is not a part of the build folder. Hence, it is not reflecting in the deployment`? Where on earth is the `.env` file located in your **repo**?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you built your NodeJS app and then updated the `.env` file for deployment. You may check the file contents by [accessing Kudu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/resources-kudu#access-kudu-for-your-app) for your app

[image]

Once confirmed the deployed `.env` file had the updated contents, it meant the deployment was succeeded, but your app couldn't read the `.env` file.

For this, you may run the `Replace Token` task in your CI pipeline **before** `npm build` or you may test to run [startup command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-nodejs?pivots=platform-linux) after deployment.